# Gradient transitioning through background-position does strange things

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a transition on a gradient background of a `<div>`. I'm trying to do it this way because I'd like to implement two different styles on my site a light one and a darker one. After choosing the right color and implementing a way to change between the two themes I thought why not build a transition to smoothen the switch between themes.

I looked up a way to transition a gradient. I found this blog: [Sapphion.com](http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/). It explains how to transition a gradient through the `background-position`.

After copying the code to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fean/VKtjX/2/) it sort of worked. It doesn't matter what I set on the `background-position` it always transitions to the full gradient from 0% to 100%. I want to transition it from 0% to 50% so that you only see 50% to 100% of the gradient. Does anyone know how to do this or did I miss something?

Comment: your fiddle is working, what's the problem?

Comment: I have a gradient with actually two gradients on it. I want to transition from the light one to the dark one. Also the `background-position` property seems to be almost obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake was to specify background-position: 100y; in the hover state.

It should have been (since you are moving the gradient in the vertical direction)

```
background-position-y: -100px;
```

full CSS:

```
#DemoGradient{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #45484d 50%, #000000 100%);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    background-size:1px 200px;  /* correct value if you want it to get at 50% */
    border-radius: 10px;  
    border: 1px solid #839DB0;  
    cursor:pointer;  
    width: 150px;  
    height: 100px;  
}  
#DemoGradient:Hover{  
    background-position-y: -100px;
}
```

## [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/VKtjX/4/)